# Is there an easy way to backup Oracle SQL Developer's User Snippets?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I love Oracle SQL Developer so I find myself using it a lot to complete my daily tasks. The thing is that my collection of custom snippets only keeps growing so I though it'd be interesting to learn how to backup them.

Before asking blindly I did a bit of work trying to figure out how. I've performed a search within the application's folder by "snippet" and found the following file:

```
oracle.sqldeveloper.snippet.jar
```

which quite probably contains my beloved pieces of code. I could just save that file hoping the best, but why not doing it the right way and perhaps being able to, say, only backup the ones and I've created, avoiding the ones that came out-of-the-box, et cétera?

Any suggestion would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On my WinXP machine, I found my User Snippets at:

`C:\Documents and Settings\eddie\Application Data\SQL Developer\UserSnippets.xml`

PS: Replace *eddie* with your username.

Comment: Wow, it's there! Thanks much! Clearly for some reason Windows search is not indexing that location.

Answer (score 7):

Agreeing with Eddie Awad, just copy the xml file. And for **windows7** the sqldeveloper User-Snippets file can be found here:

C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\UserSnippets.xml

Comment: Confirm and update that this is valid for Windows 10. Also, to go a slightly more dynamic way: you can just put this into the "Run" dialog:  `"%APPDATA%\SQL Developer\" ` to open Windows Explorer to appropriate path.

Answer (score 3):

If you use SQL Developer on Mac OS X, then the snippets can be found in ~/Library/Application Support/SQL Developer/UserSnippets.xml

Answer (score 2):

Are you running on Windows? Check your "C:\Documents and Settings\\Application Data\SQL Developer" directory for a UserSnippets.xml file, it contains all user defined snippets.

Also, check the online help for "Location of User-Related Information" topic. It has location of files that hold other user defined info.

-Dave

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a package on the Oracle server for daily maintenance that way it's stored with your DB and in your DB backups?

EDIT:  I do this and find it even easier to use them later on when performing routine maintenance tasks.  Being able to call a packaged procedure is really, REALLY handy sometimes.

Comment: Thanks much for your comment! I'd have to sort of disagree with you here, I don't think that performing such a server-side operation would be the best way to backup user snippets.

Comment: What are you backing up?  Snippets of SQL?

Your "daily tasks" you use "a lot" are going to be performed much faster as pre-compiled procedures rather than run-once statements.  Not only do you gain a performance standard, you gain the backup capability.

However, if these snippets you want to save are user-specific then I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 1):

Agreeing with Spyder -

C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\UserSnippets.xml

is the place. But I only found this after creating my first new Snippet.

After that, I was able to edit the xml to add new snippets and new categories. Once a change is made to the xml, SQLDev has to be relaunched. (And since it's an xml, I'm going to see if I can save it to Git to share amongst my team when I get a minute...)

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Developer 3.2.20.09 on OS X Mountain Lion (10.8.*), the snippet file is located in `~/.sqldeveloper/UserSnippets.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

On OS-X Yosemite (10.10.5) I found the current UserSnippets.xml for the current  SQL Developer ( Version 4.1.0.19 ) also in 
`~/.sqldeveloper/UserSnippets.xml`